# casting with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm in an introductory course and I am curious about casting with pointers.

What would be the difference between:

```
*(uint32_t*)(p) 
(uint32_t)(*p)
```

`p` is a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*(uint32_t*)(p)
```

Extracts 32 unsigned bits at the memory location.

```
(uint32_t)(*p)
```

Extracts p from the memory location in its native type, and cast that type to a 32 bit unsigned int.

The results will probably be most notable if p is a floating point type. When extracted the first way you can see the resulting bitwise format of a floating point number (sign|mantissa|exponent). When extracted the second way the number is converted to an integer, probably via some form of truncation.

Here's a fun example program:

```
main(){
    float x = 1.25, *xp = &x;
    uint32_t x1 = (uint32_t)(*xp);
    uint32_t x2 = *(uint32_t *)(xp);
    printf("x1 = %x\nx2 = %x\n",x1,x2);
}
```

and the output:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 3fa00000
```

Comment: +1 for explaining WHY it makes a difference which way you do it.

Comment: Another important difference is that the first can crash if `p` doesn't point to at least 4 bytes of memory (it could point to the last byte of a page which is not followed by another mapped page), or if `p` isn't correctly aligned for a 32-bit read (x86 typically doesn't care, other processors are not always so forgiving).

Comment: The version interpreting the raw bits as an integer violates the strict aliasing rule, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: This doesn't violate strict aliasing. The only lvalues here are x,x1, and x2. Unless I am mistaken, they all point to different memory locations. We would be violating strict aliasing if we kept the result of `(uint32_t *)(xp)` in its own lvaulue, but that temporary is handily discarded.

Answer (score 0):

In former, first you are casting `p` to `uint32_t*` and then dereferencing it.
In latter, first you are dereferencing `p` and then casting it to `uint32_t`.